# how to loop through array to create specific 6 digit combinations

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have a table of 10 rows that I generate with some php code. From this table I want to assemble every combination of 6 digits without repeating from each row.
For example:

Table looks like this:

Row1 - 13  18   31  36  42  48

Row2 - 07   09  17  27  28  32

Row3 - 01   20  27  37  47  49

Row4 - 04   20  33  38  39  45

Row5 - 13   22  32  37  39  48

Row6 - 01   26  29  30  31  43

Row7 - 10   24  27  29  40  46

Row8 - 01   08  14  36  37  49

Row9 - 01   03  10  18  19  46

Row10- 04   12  24  28  38  42

(*i added the zeros in front of single digits for readability only)
I am trying to loop through and not duplicate any row, but pull one number per row for only 6 digits.
With this set of numbers my output would be:

13,07,01,04,13,01

13,07,01,04,13,26

13,07,01,04,13,29

13,07,01,04,13,30

13,07,01,04,13,31

13,07,01,04,13,43

13,07,01,04,13,10

13,07,01,04,13,24

13,07,01,04,13,27

13,07,01,04,13,29

13,07,01,04,13,40

13,07,01,04,13,46

13,07,01,04,13,1

13,07,01,04,13,8

13,07,01,04,13,14...

and so on; until all the 6th place digits have been exhausted, then the 5th place would increment to the next place and all the 6th place value would be assembled again. and continue up through all the place values.It should not assemble number combinations from the same row i.e. 13,18,7,1,4,13 would not be assembled because 13 & 18 are on the same row. *but it is possible to have 13 & 18 in the same combination because 18 is also on row 9. My point being that i am not trying to exclude 13 and 18 from ever being in a combination together because they are on the same line, but instead I am trying to make the combinations based on the place values in the table, and the loop would not create combinations based on the same row place value, regardless of the number in that place value.

Another way to look at it is with the array I compiled from the db and made the table from.
I want combinations to be like:

$array[0][0], $array[1][0], $array[2][0], $array[3][0], $array[4][0], $array[5][0]

$array[0][0], $array[1][0], $array[2][0], $array[3][0], $array[4][0], $array[5][1]

$array[0][0], $array[1][0], $array[2][0], $array[3][0], $array[4][0], $array[5][2]

$array[0][0], $array[1][0], $array[2][0], $array[3][0], $array[4][0], $array[5][3]

$array[0][0], $array[1][0], $array[2][0], $array[3][0], $array[4][0], $array[5][4]

$array[0][0], $array[1][0], $array[2][0], $array[3][0], $array[4][0], $array[5][5]

$array[0][0], $array[1][0], $array[2][0], $array[3][0], $array[4][1], $array[5][0]

$array[0][0], $array[1][0], $array[2][0], $array[3][0], $array[4][1], $array[5][1]

$array[0][0], $array[1][0], $array[2][0], $array[3][0], $array[4][1], $array[5][2]

$array[0][0], $array[1][0], $array[2][0], $array[3][0], $array[4][1], $array[5][3]

$array[0][0], $array[1][0], $array[2][0], $array[3][0], $array[4][1], $array[5][4]

$array[0][0], $array[1][0], $array[2][0], $array[3][0], $array[4][1], $array[5][5]

$array[0][0], $array[1][0], $array[2][0], $array[3][0], $array[4][2], $array[5][0]

$array[0][0], $array[1][0], $array[2][0], $array[3][0], $array[4][2], $array[5][1]

$array[0][0], $array[1][0], $array[2][0], $array[3][0], $array[4][2], $array[5][2]...

Hopefully by this point I have explained the intended result well enough. I've tried to use a for loop like so, but I am at a loss how to iterate the next level once I reach the end of the  6th place value.

```
            $tr = 0;
            $td = 0;
            for($i = 0;$i < 6;$i++){
                $combo[] = array($makeArray[$tr][$td],$makeArray[$tr+1][$td],$makeArray[$tr+2][$td],$makeArray[$tr+3][$td],$makeArray[$tr+4][$td],$makeArray[$tr+5][$td]);
                $tr++
            }
```

I thought I could use $tr++ somehow or maybe nest another "for" loop or "while" loop inside a loop to make this happen. but I can't figure it out. Any ideas, best method, pr best practices?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that what you are asking is a list with close to 10 million entries. This is because you first want to take every combination of 6 rows out of 10 rows, which is:

```
  10! 
------- = 210
6! . 4!
```

And for each of those, you want to take from each row an element, and produce any combination of such a selection in the selected 6 rows. This is:

```
6^6 = 46 656
```

The product of both numbers represents all possibilities:

```
= 9 797 760
```

The code to produce this, could use these two helper functions:

```
function combinations($a, $count, $from = 0) {
    if (!$count) return [[]];
    foreach (range($from, count($a)-$count) as $i) {
        foreach (combinations($a, $count-1, $i+1) as $combi) {
            $result[] = array_merge([$a[$i]], $combi);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

function ordered_combinations($size, $count) {
    foreach (range(0, pow($size, $count)-1) as $i) {
        $row = [];
        foreach (range(0, $count-1) as $j) {
            array_unshift($row, $i % $size);
            $i = floor($i / $size); 
        }
        $result[] = $row;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Then, given the `$array`, you could use these functions as follows:

```
$size = 6; // number of rows to combine
$choices = ordered_combinations(count($array[0]), $size);
foreach(combinations($array, $size) as $combi) {
    foreach($choices as $choice) {
        $row = [];
        foreach($choice as $i => $choice) {
            $row[] = $combi[$i][$choice];
        }
        $result[] = $row;
    }
}
```

Now the `$result` variable will have these millions of rows, each having 6 numbers.

It would be prudent to first try it out with `$size=2`, which means you only want to produce rows with 2 elements (from 2 rows), and then increase.